# Referencing the Set Property from the Get Property

Tags: vba, class-design

I came across this bit of vba code posted in another SO question. Is there any significance in referencing the Set property in the Get Property of a class?

`Private WithEvents mctlEventButton As MSForms.CommandButton`

`Public Property Set EventButton(ctlButton As MSForms.CommandButton)`
`Set mctlEventButton = ctlButton`
`End Property`

Why do this? ...

`Public Property Get EventButton() As MSForms.CommandButton`
`Set EventButton = mctlEventButton`
`End Property`

The code was showing how to use `collections` to iterate through a group of controls. The question wasnt really about that part of the code, so it wasnt addressed in the question. Using the example from the question, I ran into an issue with the bit I posted here because the Get Property was using the Set property. So when would that be useful?

Here is the link to the SO Question: [object array or collection in VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909763/object-array-or-collection-in-vba-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Property Get EventButton() As MSForms.CommandButton
   Set EventButton = mctlEventButton
End Property
```

In the code above, `Set EventButton = mctlEventButton` **won't** call the following (try stepping through the code & you will see that it doesn't step into `Set`)

```
Public Property Set EventButton(ctlButton As MSForms.CommandButton)
   Set mctlEventButton = ctlButton
End Property
```

On the other hand, this of it as a statement that is used to return a value.
Effectively, think of `Get` as

```
Public function EventButton() As MSForms.CommandButton
   Set EventButton = mctlEventButton  'returning the value from the function
End Property
```

wrapped in form of a property for developers to do get/set.

Comment: I had a whole reponse lined up about how when I stepped into the code, it **did** step into the `set` statement. Then I realized that my `Get` and `Set` properties were named differently. Making them the same name yields the behavior you describe. thank you for your explanation. :)