# VBA Excel UserForm. How to determine which image has been clicked

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform with 10 images inside 10 ImageBoxes. I know that I can determine what image has been clicked like this:

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()
    MsgBox "Image 1 clicked!"
End Sub
```

But as there are 10 images, do I have to repeat 10 times the above code?

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()
    MsgBox "Image 1 clicked!"
End Sub

Private Sub Image2_Click()
    MsgBox "Image 2 clicked!"
End Sub

Private Sub Image3_Click()
    MsgBox "Image 3 clicked!"
End Sub

Private Sub Image4_Click()
    MsgBox "Image 4 clicked!"
End Sub

etc
```

Or there's a more elegant and concise method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [object array or collection in VBA Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909763/object-array-or-collection-in-vba-excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use event sinking, so in a class module, called `cls_CustomImage` have the following

```
Private WithEvents customImage As Image

Public Sub InitialiseCustomImage(imgToCusomise As Image)
    Set customImage = imgToCusomise
End Sub
Private Sub customImage_Click()
    MsgBox customImage.Name
End Sub
```

Then in your user form opening have the following

```
Public colCustomImages As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ctl As Control
Dim clsCustomImage As cls_CustomImage

Set colCustomImages = New Collection

For Each ctl In Me.Controls

    If TypeName(ctl) = "Image" Then
        Set clsCustomImage = New cls_CustomImage
        clsCustomImage.InitialiseCustomImage ctl
        colCustomImages.Add clsCustomImage
    End If

Next ctl
End Sub
```

Comment: This is about the only way I know of.  This goes along with http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/05/vba-control-arrays/