# How To Use Private Sub Checkbox Name variable in Code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an ActiveX Checkbox in Excel that when clicked will change a cell value to add 1.

I need to repeat this VBA code when I use the same Checkbox in a different Cell Value, which I need to repeat many times.

How do I reference the automatically generated checkbox name variable in the VBA code for each new cell value?

This is for a Excel spreadsheet that I use to update a database when new reports are turned in with "checked" information on it.

```
Private Sub CheckBox21_Click()

Range("L2").Activate

    'Don't want to type CheckBoxXX each time, just find way to automatically reference?'
    If CheckBox21.Value = True Then
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
    Else
        If ActiveCell.Value > 0 Then
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value - 1
    Else
        End If
    End If


_____________________________________________________________________________
'Next line'

Private Sub CheckBox22_Click()

Range("L2").Activate

    If CheckBox22.Value = True Then
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
    Else
        If ActiveCell.Value > 0 Then
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value - 1
    Else
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I don't want to type `CheckBoxXX` each time, just to automatically reference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [object array or collection in VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1909763/11683)

Comment: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: Is there a reason you picked Active X over Form Control though?

Comment: I figured Active X would be enough to complete my code, which is a fairly simple one.  If Form Ctrl is the better option please let me know??

Comment: GSerg the reference you gave could solve the problem but how do I reference the CheckBox value in the code... Me.CheckBox.Value = True Then doesn't seem to work??

Comment: @MattGilbert Pass the checkbox as a parameter to the common handler.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that .... I'm very new to this ...